# How to open only default android camera in cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, camera

How to open only default android camera in cordova:
In my phone tow camera one is default camera and second is Beautify aap. I want to open only my default camera only by using cordova.

Answer (score 1):

please use following plugin

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
```

this function will open camera app,

```
$scope.takePicture = function (options) {

      var options = {
         quality : 75,
         targetWidth: 200,
         targetHeight: 200,
         sourceType: 1
      };

      Camera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
         $scope.picture = imageData;;
      }, function(err) {
         console.log(err);
      });

   };
```

if above function is opening **Beautify camera app**,then you have selected it as default camera app,please check in phone settings. 
**[Clear defaults](http://www.androidauthority.com/change-default-apps-android-2-633572/)** from **Beautify camera app**

For references:

**[Tutorial 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ionic/ionic_camera.htm) 
[Tutorial 2](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/use-android-ios-camera-ionic-framework/)**